# Property load cannot be found for forwarded class object pdfmemdocument

Tags: ios, podofo

I'm using PoDoFo library for digital signature on pdf. its working fine for new pdf but now I want to implement same functionality for existed pdf and while doing that I am getting following prob.

[image]